# show html if products in the cart belong to a specific category

Tags: magento-1.9, category

So I'm trying to show some html code on my order confirmation page IF
the products in the cart belong to a certain category. To clarify there are only two different categories and the user can only chose one of them, so all the products in the cart will be part of the same category.

I have tried this:

```
<?php
   $categoryId = 426;
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
?>
     <?php if($quote->hasCategoryId($categoryId)): ?>
          <p>show text blah blah </p>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

But the text doesn't show even though all the products in the cart are from this category.
Any ideas how to do this or what I did wrong?

Comment: add your magento version tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it working with this, in case it helps anybody else:

```
  <?php
    $allowcheckout=true;
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
    foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $categorytId = $item->getCategoryId();
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($categoryId);
                     if($category->getAllowcheckout()==426){
                     $allowcheckout=true;
                     break;
                    }
                   }
        ?>
  <?php if($allowcheckout): ?>
       <p>test</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You should click the accepted answer button on your answer since it solved your problem. That will cause the question to show up as resolved.